# Selecting a row from sql database based on a value in a specific column in java

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm currently working on a project where we have an inventory for an optical lens company which is stored in a database. I've connected my database to my java program and im just having an issue selecting a row based on a column value. Im doing this by

```
String name=lookUpName.getText();

            try (
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/productitem?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC",
                            "root", "123456789"); // for MySQL only
                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ) {

                String strSelect = "select * from products where productName= "+name+"";
                System.out.println("The SQL statement is: " + strSelect + "\n"); // Echo For debugging

                ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(strSelect);
                }
                rset.close();
```

when it tries to execute the query it gives me an error. but if i run a regular query using the sql console like `select *
from products where productName='golden vintage';` it works. can someone help me with the java part.

the debugging output i have in there shows
The SQL statement is: select * from products where productName= golden vintage

The error I get is:

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'vintage' at line 1

Comment: can you show the error ?

Comment: @Deadpool I added the error

Comment: Here you have singled quotes `productName='golden vintage';` and here you don't `where productName= "+name+"";`  But anyway please consider using a PreparedStatement class see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: @ScaryWombat i tried using single quotes in my java program but it didnt work. The single quotes worked for the sql console tho.

Comment: Please show the actual code you are using (edit question) and add the output of `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Definitely need to quote the name. It sould read `where productName= '"+name+"'";`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using the Prepared Statements

```
 String strSelect = "select * from products where productName= ?";

        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(strSelect);
        st.setString(1,name);

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String productid = rs.getString(1);
            String productColors=rs.getString(2);
            String productPrices = rs.getString(3);
            String productBrands=rs.getString(4);
            String productStyles = rs.getString(5);
            String productNames=rs.getString(6);
            System.out.println(productid +" "+productNames + " " +productBrands + " " + productStyles + " " + productColors + " " + productPrices);
        }
```